# Terminological conventions regarding group actions

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, terminology, universal-algebra

Suppose:

- $G$ is a group
- $T$ is a Lawvere theory ("algebraic theory") and $X$ is a $T$-algebra

What conventions surround the phrase: "action of $G$ on $X$"?

In particular, does this mean:

- a homomorphism $G \rightarrow \mathrm{Aut}_{\mathrm{Mod}(T)}(X)$, or
- a homomorphism $G \rightarrow \mathrm{Aut}_{\mathbf{Set}}(X)$?

Comment: I've added the "category-theory" and "universal-algebra" tags.

Comment: Almost certainly it means the former. What reason do you have for thinking that it means the latter?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, only that this is old terminology and odd conventions may surround its use. Note: the question is not: "What *should* the conventions be regarding the use of this term," but rather, "What *are* they?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't take my answer as a reference, but from my experience, notably in French, "action of $G$ on $X$" usually refers to a set-action (i.e. an homomorphism $G \to \operatorname{Aut}_{\mathbf{Set}}(X)$) while "representation of $G$ on/in $X$" refers to an homomorphism $G \to \operatorname{Aut}_{\operatorname{Mod}(T)}(X)$.

For example, one talks about "linear representations" or "representations in Lie algebra". If you're writing something though, the better is still to precisely state your usage.